# How to add global ranking annotation to subsequent Django queries?

Tags: django, orm

I have a Django model that looks like this:

```
class LeaderboardScore(models.Model):
  score = models.FloatField()
  player_account = models.ForeignKey(PlayerAccount, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
```

This represents top scores in a game. The scores are ranked by score descending and timestamp ascending, so if two scores are the same, the earliest score is ranked higher.

Every time I do a query on the leaderboards, I'd like to include the global ranking of each instance in the query result. I can do that successfully when I'm querying all the scores like so:

```
from django.db.models import F, Window
from django.db.models.functions import DenseRank

lq = LeaderboardScore.objects.filter(leaderboard__id=1).annotate(
  rank=Window(
    expression=DenseRank(),
    order_by=[F('score').desc(), F('timestamp').asc()]
  )
)
```

This will correctly at a rank field with the ranking. But if I take the above query and filter it by player_account like so:

```
# rank will be 1, but should be the global ranking
lq.filter(player_account__id=123)[0].rank
```

then the ranking resets so that the first item in the query has the rank of 1, even though its global rank should be different. How do I preserve the global ranking?

Comment: leaderboard what model is this field in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out how to do this Django's ORM, but I was able to use SQL as temporary solution:

```sql
WITH ranked_leaderboard AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    score,
    timestamp,
    player_account_id,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY score DESC, timestamp ASC) AS rank
  FROM
    leaderboards_leaderboardscore
  WHERE
    leaderboard_id = 1
)
SELECT
  id,
  score,
  timestamp,
  rank
FROM
  ranked_leaderboard
WHERE
  player_account_id = 123
ORDER BY
  score DESC, timestamp ASC
```

This isn't an ideal solution as it only works when I'm searching for a particular player -- I have other queries that might be composed of an arbitrary list of players, which I had use a non-optimal solution for.